# Spring Jackson java.time Deserialization: arguments mismatched

Tags: json, spring, java-8, jackson

How do I deserialize Java 8 time API classes?

Here's what I've done:

Included dependency: `compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")`

Request body to be deserialized into:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.LocalDateDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.ser.LocalDateSerializer;

public class TestRequest {
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "YYYY-MM-dd")
    LocalDate localDate;
}
```

Spring Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity test(@RequestBody TestRequest testRequest) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(testRequest);
}
```

JSON Request Body:

```
{ "localDate": "2017-11-01" }
```

The Exception:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of TestRequest, problem: argument type mismatch`

Answer (score 1):

you should use [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) instead of jackson-datatype-jsr310 to serialize or deserialize java 8 classes.